# One Sutta / Text which covers all of Buddha's Teaching

Tags: personal-practice, reference-request

Which is the one Sutta/Text that covers all of Buddha's Teaching? I require only one book which I can carry with me and it should have Buddha's delivery in original language and its translation in English.

Comment: Could try Bhikkhu Bodhi's excellent "In the Buddha's Words: An Anthology of Discourses from the Pali Canon". It should be light enough to carry around with you.

Comment: If you have time to compile your own book, take a look at http://dharmafarer.org/

Answer (score 3):

You'd be hard pressed to find a single sutta that covers everything.  The suttas really don't work that way.  To compound your difficulty, you'd be even harder pressed to find an English/Pāli version of any text!  If I had to pick one sutta from the original canon, however, I think I'd go with the [Sāmaññaphala Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.02.0.than.html).  It does an excellent job of providing a bird's eye view of the gradual training in the least amount of space.  You can find the Pāli version of the text [here](http://www.tipitaka.org/romn/).  It's in the Tipiṭaka under the Suttapiṭaka, Dīga Nikāya, Sīlakkhandhavaggapāḷi, Sāmaññaphalasuttaṃ.  (I'd appreciate if anyone can link that directly!)  A bound copy is available [here](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/the-fruit-of-the-homeless-life-silachara-bhikkhu/1122153141?ean=9781330091616&st=PLA&sid=BNB_DRS_Core%20Shopping%20Books_00000000&2sid=Google_&sourceId=PLGoP547&k_clickid=3x547) - but again, no Pāli.  Bhikkhu Bodhi also did an excellent translation of the sutta and its commentaries.  That's available [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001Y0RRPG).  If you are going to spend the money, go with his version.

There are other single, bound texts that are far more detailed, technical, and honestly, I'd say more helpful.  Key among these is the lengthy [Visuddhimagga](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf) written by Buddhaghosa.  Seriously, that guy spares no expense on detail.  I swear he thought he was getting paid by the word!  It also meets your requirement in that it is written in the [supposed] language of the Buddha - Pāli.  Mind, it was written several centuries after the Buddha's death.  The original text is also available on tipitaka.org.  It's under Anya, Visuddhimagga.  [A bound copy of this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1928706010) weighs about five pounds.  I'm not kidding.  It's not something you'd want to carry around with you.  A dual language version would be enormous!

Comment: +1. BTW Visuddhimagga was written about 8 centuries after Buddha's death... long after some of the Mahayana texts.

Answer (score 2):

> The non-doing of any evil, the performance of what's skillful, the
>   cleansing of one's own mind:
>       this is the teaching
>       of the Awakened. [•](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.14.than_en.html#dhp-183)

No need to carry anything with you. Discard this fear and clinging, Mr/Mrs is able to remember that, and then there is all way to simply stay with that.

*(Note: this answer has not been given with the agreement to be means of trade or the purpose of/for trade and/or keep people trapped and bound. How you handle it lies in your sphere, but does not excuse the deed here either.)*

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the book [In The Buddha's Words](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0861714911) by [Bhikkhu Bodhi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhikkhu_Bodhi). It is an anthology or selection of translated suttas from the Pali canon. It is also thematically and systematically arranged. You can look at the Table of Contents on the Amazon page I linked. It is 512 pages long, which is quite alright.

If you want a free or online equivalent version of the book above, with the original Pali text accessible, please see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/38820/471) for an equivalent version.

Comment: Is thread necromancy actually allowed here?

Comment: @Remyla Check out the [necromancer badge](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) and [revival badge](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/revival).

Comment: Ok nice, I just did not know, obviously normally Necromancy is a no no in forums.