# Good source of mantras with their meanings

Tags: pali-language, mantra

Where can I find a reliable list of mantras with their respective translations?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/bookchant.pdf

https://www.amaravati.org/dhamma-books/chanting-book/

These are chantings. The translations are also present. Hope this helps :)